# How to use wget to download large osm dataset?

Tags: wget, openstreetmap, large-files

I want to create a global dataset of wetlands using the OSM database. As there are problems for huge datasets if I use the overpass-turbo or so, I thought I could use wget to download the planet file and filter it for only the data I'm interested in. Problem is, I don't know much about wget. So I wanted to know whether there is a way to filter the data from the planet file while downloading and unzipping it?

In general I'm looking for the least time and disk-space consuming way to get to that data. Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` is just a tool for downloading, it can't filter on the fly. There is probably a chance that you can pipe the data to a second tool which does filtering on the fly but I don't see any advantage here. And the disadvantage is that you can't verify the file checksum afterwards.

Download the planet and filter it afterwards using [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) or [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter).